# Does wifi direct activation disconnect an active WLAN?

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifi

I'd like to know if on Android, just in case I'm connected to a WLAN when i start a p2p connection with wifi-direct, the WLAN gets disconnected or not? Can wifi-direct work even if a WLAN is active? Is there any exception?
Thanks!

Comment: You could have tried it. But yes, Wifi Direct immediately disconnects wlan.

Comment: Thank you @323go. I tried and it hasn't been disconnected as I expected. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 1):

At a very high level it depends on the Wi-Fi hardware capability. Some hardware supports multiple roles (legacy wifi, p2p) simultaneously and some don't.